# How to merge 2 complicated data frames in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have 2 pandas data frames.

```
dictionary1 = {'match_up' : ['1985_1116_1234' , '1985_1116_1475', '1985_1234_1172', '1985_1475_2132',  '1985_1242_1325'], \
               'result': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 'year':[1985,1985,1985,1985,1985]  }


dictionary2 = {'team' : [1234 , 1475,  2132, 1172, 1242, 1116 , 1325], 'win_A_B': [0.667, 0.636, 0.621, 0.629, 0.615,0.943, 0.763], \
               'year':[1985,1985,1985,1985,1985,1985,1985] }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dictionary1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dictionary2)

df1:
           match_up     result  year
    0   1985_1116_1234    1     1985
    1   1985_1116_1475    1     1985
    2   1985_1234_1172    0     1985
    3   1985_1475_2132    0     1985
    4   1985_1242_1325    1     1985

df2:
    team      win_A_B    year
    1234      0.667      1985
    1475      0.636      1985 
    2132      0.621      1985
    1172      0.629      1985
    1242      0.615      1985
    1116      0.943      1985
    1325      0.763      1985
```

The column value in  data frame `df1` is a matchup of the column `team` in the data frame `df2`. The column `team` in `df2` are all unique values.

I need to combine the above 2  data frames in the following manner:

```
           match_up     result  year   team_A   team_B    win_A    win_B
    0   1985_1116_1234    1     1985    1116      1234     0.943    0.667    
    1   1985_1116_1475    1     1985    1116       1475    0.943     0.636
    2   1985_1234_1172    0     1985    1234       1172    0.667     0.629
    3   1985_1475_2132    0     1985    1475       2132    0.636    0.621
    4   1985_1242_1325    1     1985    1242       1325    0.615    0.763
```

I know I have already asked similar questions in pandas. I am new to pandas, so please bear with me if I ask some questions like this.

Comment: If you provide the data in an easy form for us to import, it would be helpful.

Comment: @cge ok let me edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work:

```
d_teams=pd.DataFrame( [[int(y) for y in x.split('_')[1:]] \
            for x in df1.match_up], columns=('team_A', 'team_B') )
merged=pd.concat((df1,d_teams),axis=1)
df2i=df2.set_index('team')
merged['win_A']=df2i.ix[merged.team_A].reset_index().win_A_B
merged['win_B']=df2i.ix[merged.team_B].reset_index().win_A_B
```

First, we create `d_teams`, which is a DataFrame that is composed of the match_up column, split by '_', and turned into ints. We throw away the year, because it's already included in df1, and just keep team_A and team_B. Then we create a merged dataframe by concatenating this with df1.

Next, we create `df2i`, which is df2 indexed by team. Then we can just index with merged.team_A or merged.team_B to get the win values. However, we don't want the results to be indexed by those teams, so we reset the index first.

Comment: can you explain `merged['win_A']=df2i.ix[merged.team_A].reset_index().win_A_B
` this command?

Comment: `merged.team_A` is the list of `team_A` values in `merged`. Since we've made team values the index of `df2i`, `df2i.ix[merged.team_A]` gives us a DataFrame of rows from `df2i` that correspond to the `team_A` values. Then we remove the team index with `reset_index()`, and select the `win_A_B` column from that DataFrame. We then assign it to the `win_A` column in `merged`.

Comment: Yes I got it.  amazing explanation!!

Comment: one simple query-> `[[int(y) for y in x.split('_')[1:]] for x in df1.match_up]` gives me the following output:  `[[1116, 1234], [1116, 1475], [1234, 1172], [1475, 2132], [1242, 1325]]` . Now how does passing this  `d_teams=pd.DataFrame( [[int(y) for y in x.split('_')[1:]] \
            for x in df1.match_up], columns=('team_A', 'team_B') ` assigns the first values in my inner list as the first column and second values as my second column. In a dictionary I know that keys become my columns and values becomes my rows. Is there any similar concept associated with this list of lists?